# ngRoute infinite loop when changing path on a root event

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm not sure why, but when I catch an event from JQuery, update the route and notify Angular of the change, it goes into an infinite route. It's easy to reproduce, say you have a screen like this:

[image]

The click of the button is handled by jQuery, because the jquery library doesn't seem to work in a directive so I put it in a service. Once the controller loads I initialize this. Then when the user clicks that button, I catch this jquery event, and raise a new event on the root scope so that I know to navigate to the new view. Here's the code:

```
(function(angular, $) {
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

  app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider',
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'list.html',
            controller: 'ListController' 
        });

        // The view I am trying to reach via jquery event.
        $routeProvider.when('/Edit', {
            templateUrl: 'edit.html',
            controller: 'ListController' 
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
    }]);

    app.controller('ListController', 
      function ListController($scope, $rootScope, $location, JQuerySerivce) {
        // Initialize the button click listener.
        JQuerySerivce.registerBtn();

        $rootScope.$on('clicked', function() {
          $location.path("./Edit"); 
          // Notify angular stuff happened.
          $scope.$apply();
        });
    });

    app.controller('EditController', function EditController() {
      console.log("Edit view loaded!");
    });

    app.factory("JQuerySerivce", function ($rootScope){
      return {
        registerBtn: function() {
          $('#jqueryBtn').on('click', function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('clicked');
          });
        }
      };
    });

})(angular, jQuery);
```

The working plunker example:

https://embed.plnkr.co/WIwRreYtofGKQWdjTeQx/

[EDIT]

To clarify my question, how can I prevent this infinite loop from happening? All of the other quesitons I've found concerning routing and infinite loops have usually been some sort of mistake that introduces a loop. In this case I'm just navigating and the framework is dying. Maybe my approach is wrong? I'm open to changing it if anyone has an alternative. I can't escape the jquery event though :/ Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$location.path("/Edit");`

instead of

`$location.path("./Edit");`

?

Comment: Oh my god, yes, that works! I basically forgot that I'm interacting with the angular routing framework instead of the browser. I'm a little embarrassed lol